# Adding Ember.js frontend app to Node.js backend app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a running ember.js frontend app. Also have a node.js backend app which can do basic CRUD operations from MongoDB. Using Postman I can see that my node.js app is returning JSON data properly.

I want my frontend to use the backend to do CRUD operations on MongoDB. I am new to ember.js so I want a guideline where I can understand to use the JSON data from the node.js app and use with ember.js frontend.

My ember.js app already is using a mock server. It has a "dist" folder inside.

My adapter/application.js file in ember.js frontend:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api' 
});
```

I want to use my localhost:3000 node server here. Do not know where to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DS.RESTAdapter` has a [`host` property](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.11/classes/RESTAdapter/properties/host?anchor=host) that allows you to configure the host used:

```js
// app/adapters/application.js
import RESTAdapter from '@ember-data/adapter/rest';

export default RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```

But I would not recommend to point that one to a local development server cause that reduces your flexibility. E.g. a team colleague of yours may want to start the local instance on another port. I would recommend to use the `--proxy` option of Ember CLI's `serve` command:

```
ember serve --proxy http://localhost:3000
```

This will proxy the requests to your local development server.

You may need to customize the adapter and serializer if your API isn't following the defaults of Ember Data's `RESTAdapter` and `RESTSerializer`. Please have a look in the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/) for a quick introduction to do so.

Comment: Thanks! Used RESTAdapter in the application.js with http://localhost:3000 and then used serializer. Got an error so I changed the DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend to DS.JSONSerializer.extend in the serializer>application.js folder. Set the primaryKey to an unique value name of my fetching data. So far, it's able to do GET operations and showing the data.